# Python SqlAlchemy order_by DateTime?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SqlAlchemy to store some objects with a DateTime field:

```
my_date = Field(DateTime())
```

I'd like to run a query to retrieve the most recent few objects (Entities with the my_date field that are the most recent).

I've tried the following:

```
entities = MyEntity.query.order_by(MyEntity.time).limit(3).all()
entities = MyEntity.query.order_by(-MyEntity.time).limit(3).all()
```

But these queries return the same objects in the same order. The SqlAlchemy documentation notes the use of the '-' to reverse the order, but I'm surely missing something here.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
entities = MyEntity.query.order_by(desc(MyEntity.time)).limit(3).all()
```

You might need to:

```
from sqlalchemy import desc
```

Here's [some documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=desc#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.desc).

Another option is this:

```
stmt = select([users_table]).order_by(users_table.c.name.desc())
```

Comment: This operation is painfully slow on my database.  Is there a faster way?

Comment: @kalu: Are you using appropriate indexes? Try looking at the generated SQL, and profile it.

Comment: @thirtydot Is there a way to select records between row numbers instead of limiting it to 3 and so? Say we have 100 records, I need rows from 10 to 20 order by name desc

Comment: @KishorkumarR: You need [`offset()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=offset#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.offset) combined with `limit()` (or: [`slice()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=offset#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.slice)). Make sure you understand how it works in the underlying SQL for your database. It's different between MySQL and MSSQL, for example. Also, your comment is not really related to my answer, next time ask a new question or something.

Answer (score 24):

```
entities = MyEntity.query.order_by(MyEntity.my_date.desc()).limit(3).all()
```

should work.

Comment: I prefer this because it avoids an `import`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this

```
from sqlalchemy import desc

db.session.query(MyEntity).order_by(desc(MyEntity.time))
```