# How do you sort by datetime in sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to retrieve the latest entry of a data that is entered into the database object.

```
database_object = db(pid=1, content_entered=datetime.datetime.utcnow())

Assume I add multiple database_object into db and have multiple entry, I want to query the latest entry.
```

I tried to do this:

```
database_object.query.filter_by(
        pid=1).order_by(desc(db.content_entered)).first()
```

But I am getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: ORDER BY expression expected, got datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 2, 9, 28, 57, 973620).
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: this thread solved the problem for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582264/python-sqlalchemy-order-by-datetime

Comment: The argument to `desc` should be the model _class_ and attribute; you are passing an _instance_ (`database_object`).  You want `desc(db.content_entered)` or `db.content_entered.desc()`, assuming `db` is your model class.

Comment: ah nvm, I realize where I was doing wrong, I am only passing in single instance instead of whole db entry

Comment: please mark duplicate and delete, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```py
entry = database_object.query.filter_by(
    pid=1
).order_by(
    database_object.content_entered.desc()
).first()

print(entry.content_entered)
```